# Selecting Last child with jquery but 2 instances

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I have 2 divs containing DL DT DD, and I want to select each last DT of divs. But it is selecting only DT from the last DIV.

HTML:

```
<div class=pack>
<dl>
<dt>Photos</dt>
<dd>asd</dd>

<dt>Videos</dt>
<dd>asd</dd>

<dt>Infographics</dt>
<dd>ads</dd>
</dl>
</div>

<div class=pack>
<dl>
<dt>Photos</dt>
<dd>asd</dd>

<dt>Videos</dt>
<dd>asd</dd>

<dt>Infographics</dt>
<dd>ads</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.pack dl').find('dt').last().css({"background" : "none" });
```

The problem is, jquery selects only the last DT from second DIV class=pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.pack ul').each(function(){
    $(this).find('li').last().css({"background" : "none" });
});
```

Comment: GIVE DIFFERENT ID'S FOR THE DIVS

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Brad M each method works.

```
$('.pack dl').each(function(){
        $(this).find('dt').last().css({"background" : "none" });
    });
```